# Unexpected token ILLEGAL : how to remove &quote; and lines breaks from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pageload, handlebars.java

I receive a [json](/questions/tagged/json)from the server when loading a page, and it gets populated in the page using `Handelbars.java`. Till now everything's fine.

However I would like to get that [json](/questions/tagged/json)object and store it on a  [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)object this is where I fail.

When I try to store it on a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) object I do the following :

```
var jsObject = "{{output.items}}";  // the output.items is the JSON retrieved on the template
```

I get the following (`&quote;` and line breaks interpreted) :

```
{
    &quot;profile&quot;: {
        &quot;name&quot;: &quot;copernic&quot;,
        &quot;email&quot;: &quot;copernic@cop.com&quot;
    }
    ....
}
```

When I should get the following (without line breaks interpreted) :

```
{
    "profile": {
        "name": "copernic",
        "email": "copernic@cop.com"
    }
    ....
}
```

So it throws me an error on [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

When printing the json on the HTML template using `<pre>{{output}}</pre>` it looks just fine.

Do you have any idea about how can I store the [json](/questions/tagged/json)returned from the server on page loading on a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)object as I don't have much control of it since it's **NOT** coming with [json](/questions/tagged/json)?

Thank you.

Comment: "JSON object" is a misnomer... on the other hand, in what form is the JSON passed from the server to your page then? You might have to parse it, i.e. `JSON.parse()`, but then again it depends on what do you mean by "JSON returned from the server".

Comment: Neither of the above is valid JSON. Nor valid JS object initializers. And why exactly do you HTML-escape your data?

Comment: @Terry : Thanks for your reply. I have a "dynamic" webpage, with Handlebars.java as templating engine. So basically I have a Json object (on a server side term) on my template. I can easily get its elements by for example : `<p>{{profile.name}}</p>` or again in JS : `var name = "{{profile.name}}"`.
But the issue is when I want to assign the whole object to a JS variable

Comment: @Oriol : forgot to remove the semicolon and adding the `var` when writing the question :)

Comment: @Oriol : I don't escape them, that's the point, it's done automatically when trying to assign the data to the JS object.

Comment: @Copernic I meant that in JSON, property names must be quoted (in JS it's not necessary). And since the values are strings, they must be quoted too. And if you didn't escape them intentionally, you should find what escapes them and disable it, instead of attempting to unescape.

Comment: @Oriol : Thank you. They are quoted, I can see that on the server log and when printing the json on a `<pre>{{output}}</pre>` tag. But for some reason the quotes are being escaped

Answer (score 0):

Your server is serving a incorrect json format.

Your server needs to serve a json string, with double quotes.

```
{
    "profile": {
        "name": "copernic",
        "email": "copernic@cop.com"
    }
}
```

If you need to serve a well-formed json, you can try with Gson. 
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson

Comment: Thanks. But my Json looks fine on the server side (like the one you wrote :-)) My issue is that it's being escaped on the template

Comment: Oh, i see...
Did you try using triple curly braces, like {{{ob.test}}}?

Answer (score 0):

Since the content `output.items` ist a string, this is how you can proceed.

```
eval("jsObject={" + object.items.replace(/&quot;/g,'"')+"}");
```

Comment: Ok, its not the most elegant one, but it works. SInce the server sends you the correct data you might have a look at the tool/procedure that handles the AJAX request, you might check on what you wanted the ajax routine to give you back. Could it be you requested HTML instead of JASON?